# Tensorflow predicting for specific ids

Tags: python, tensorflow

im using the Tensorflow dataset api and try to predict for a multilabel classification. Its working fine but the resulting predictions have no correspondending id, so I don't know to what the prediciton belongs to.

I'm using the following code to create the dataset and predict:

```
def test_input_fn():
  filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("../input/test/*_green.png")
  dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(filenames)

  def _parse_image_data(filename):
      image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
      image_decoded = tf.image.decode_png(image_string, channels=1)
      image_reshape = tf.reshape(image_decoded, [512*512*1])
      return image_reshape

  return dataset.map(_parse_image_data).batch(8)

pred_result = estimator.predict(test_input)
```

Is there an easy way to somehow append the ids to the prediction.

Answer (score 0):

You can `return image_reshape,filename` in your `_parse_image_data(filename)` function, and modify your model function accordingly, so that for predictions it will return not only the predicted labels but also the filenames.

More detailedly, suppose your model function is `model_fn(features, labels, mode, params)`, now your `features` is no longer just `image_reshape`, but `image_shape,filename`, so basically you should change wherever you use `features` to `features[0]`; you may also need to append `features[1]` to your `predictions` (I'm assuming you name your variables like this, I can give more specific codes if you can show me your model function).

Or, if you would like a separate function that simply prints the `filenames` content :

```
def print_filenames(): 
    filenames = tf.train.match_filenames_once("../input/test/*_green.png")
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        print(sess.run(filenames))
```

In the above codes, the output is in the as-is order, so it should be the same order of your predictions.